# Why is this dynamic list comparison failing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a search that returns a result that is dynamic. So I am trying to just show a label if there are no results found. The problem i am having is i dont know how to count the result because it is dynamic and is not equal to a type.

The error message is :

> Operator '!=' Cannot be applied ot operands of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List and int

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
            {


                string keyword = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
                List<dynamic> results = SearchItems(keyword);
                List<dynamic> Cresults = SearchContacts(keyword);



               if(results != 0 || Cresults !=0)
               {


                    //bind and return
                    LVI.DataSource = results;
                    LVI.DataBind();
                    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                    //Contact Bind return
                    LVC.DataSource = Cresults;
                    LVC.DataBind();
                    //  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);


                    lvAdmin.DataSource = results;
                    lvAdmin.DataBind();


                    LVCAdmin.DataSource = Cresults;
                    LVCAdmin.DataBind();
               }
               else{

                    NoResults.Visible = true;

               }
```

Comment: Can you pick an answer if any helped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **cannot** just do:

```
if(results != 0 || Cresults !=0)
{

}
```

That way your comparing the actual `List` to `0`, which obviously fails.

Just do:

```
if(results.Count != 0 || Cresults.Count !=0)
{

}
```

Or:

```
if(results.Any() || Cresults.Any())
{

}
```

Comment: @Servy True. Updated the answer with the fix. Will teach me to copy and paste!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Count` property of the `List` class:

```
if (results.Count != 0 || Cresults.Count != 0)
{
    //rest of code
}
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7f69ad7.aspx

Answer (score 4):

you can try using count

```
if(results.Count > 0 || Cresults.Count > 0)
```